# Application-defined or object Defined error on Vlookup & IF statement

Tags: vba, if-statement, error-handling, vlookup

Hello Friends and Community,

I have been getting a VBA error with my code "Application-defined or object defined error'

Here is my code

```
Sub RSData()
Dim Column6 As Integer
Dim RowX As Integer
Dim EndofRow As Integer
EndofRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For RowX = 14 To EndofRow
If Cells(RowX, 12) = "RS" Then
    For Column6 = 13 To 34
    Cells(RowX, Column6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(RowX, 11), Worksheets("Base Data_RS").Columns("F:AH"), Column6 - 11, 0)
    Next Column6
Else: Cells(RowX, Column6) = Null
End If
Next RowX
End Sub
```

The weird thing is my previous code which is almost the same as this one runs fine, the only difference is the **sheet that I am vlooking up agasint to**, and the **if criteria**. Here is the previous code that works fine
And the error line happens in ' **Else: Cells(RowX, Column6) = Null**'
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub CRSData()
Dim Column6 As Integer
Dim RowX As Integer
Dim EndofRow As Integer
EndofRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For RowX = 14 To EndofRow
If Cells(RowX, 12) = "CRS" Then
    For Column6 = 13 To 34
    Cells(RowX, Column6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(RowX, 11), Worksheets("Base Data_CRS").Columns("F:AH"), Column6 - 11, 0)
    Next Column6
Else: Cells(RowX, Column6) = Null
End If
Next RowX
End Sub
```

Comment: Qualify your objects so the sheet reference is explicit.

Comment: If  the `For Column6 = 13 To 34` loop has not run before you call `Cells(RowX, Column6) = Null` then what is the value of `Column6`?  There is no Column zero....  *After* the loop has run then the value will be 35, which may also not be what you want.